# What does it mean to "wax hot"?

Tags: meaning

Reading "Psychology, Briefer Course" by William James I stumbled upon the following¹:

> How easily do we forget a bodily discomfort when conversation waxes
>   hot

By context, I'd suppose it's something good; but what exactly does it mean to say that a conversation *waxes hot*? I tried my best but could not relate to anything I know of either wax or hot (I'm not a native speaker).

¹ [p. 21, 1st edition Outlook, 2018.](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=hNtvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=when+conversation+waxes+hot&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj13NeI2qnoAhWmKLkGHYxiDLIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=when%20conversation%20waxes%20hot&f=false)

Comment: Wax hot, become hot.

Comment: ' ... when conversation grows animated.' This is a link-verb-like resultative construction using 'wax + (appropriate) adjective', formal or literary, applied to conversation / speech, where 'wax' means 'grow' (as the moon appears to do) or conveys a gushing,  and the adjective ('often' 'eloquent') describes the state achieved. 'Hot' here means lively ... ...  passionate.

Comment: Consider that the moon is said to "wax" and "wane".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts; looking up *wax* in a dictionary, for example, might reveal meanings you were not aware of. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2):

'Wax' can be a verb, meaning to become or enter a state:

> wax
>   verb
>   to become:
>   Brad waxed eloquent on the subject of free enterprise.

[Wax (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wax)

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge Dictionary is not too helpful. Its definition is imprecise to the point of being wrong. "to wax does not mean "to become". **To wax  = to grow,**

**Hot** = heated, i.e. animated, excited, etc.

OED

> Wax (v.) I. **To grow, increase. ([As opposed to] to wane)
>
> 1.a. intransitive. Of a plant or its parts: To increase gradually in size and vigour; to develop, sprout (up). Obsolete exc. dialect †Also, to grow in a specified habitat or situation (obsolete).**
>
> 1886   R. E. G. Cole Gloss. Words S.-W. Lincs. (at cited word)   The plums are waxing nicedly.
>
> **5. Of inanimate things:** **To increase in size**, quantity, **volume, intensity, etc.**
>
> 1869   A. Maclaren Serm. preached in Manch. 2nd Ser. xi. 201   *Energy which wanes as the years wax.*
>
> 1884   Spectator 2 Aug. 1009/2   *Glaciers..wax and wane in some mysterious manner.*

HOT:

> **8.b. Characterized by anger or hatred; angry, furious. Also: bad-tempered, quick to anger; = fiery adj.** Cf. hot-tempered adj. (b) at Compounds 3, hot-headed adj. 1.
>
> 1877   M. Oliphant Makers of Florence (ed. 2) i. 23   Donati was a hot and arrogant noble.
>
> 1935   Times 22 Aug. 11/3   Hot exchanges occurred to-day..at the International Penal and Penitentiary Congress.
>
> 1977   Audubon Jan. 48/1   Southerners became increasingly hot about shortstopping on the northern refuges and took their complaints to the Mississippi Flyway Council.

Comment: Just like _grow_ itself, _wax_ can indeed also mean ‘become’. When we say someone grows mad or waxes lyrical, we are not in any way implying that their physical shape increases in size.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet on the contrary, that is **exactly** what we are doing - wax indicates the increase towards the adjective in their demeanour  And I am not sure you understand the OED when it gives "**5. Of inanimate things: To increase in *size, quantity, volume, intensity,* etc.** You will note that some things that do not have a physical shape also "wax". The most important difference is that "wax" is a durative verb only. "Become" does not have this property and requires a stated or implied time phrase.

Answer (score 0):

When the moon changes from new (dark) to full it is said to be waxing. It is growing larger. I'm not sure if candle wax was ever part of its origin but that is what it has meant to me. The change is gradual or subtle as if by accumulation of drippings. It is used this way to describe people altering their speech, tone or purpose.

Answer (score 0):

‘**To wax hot’** means to be moving towards, or tending towards intensity or ‘hotness’ - meaning enthusiasm for  something or someone.

‘**To wax**’ is perhaps now a little quaint but is still commonly used in idioms that use ‘wax’ like:

- To **wax** ***poetic*** (suddenly gush poetry) - ‘he waxed poetic when describing his new girlfiend’
- To **wax** ***philosophical*** - to become suddenly all philosophical
- To **wax** ***eloquent*** - to suddenly gush eloquently
- To **wax** ***lyrical*** - to sing someone’s praises

Example:

- He ***waxed hot*** towards her but now seems to have gone off her completely!
- She ***waxed hot*** towards studying cookery at first, but then suddenly decided to go into mechanics instead.

***So we are talking about people’s enthusiasms ‘waxing and waning’, here - growing, or declining, in intensity - like the moon.***

**Waxing** and it’s opposite, **waning**, originally refers to ***the*** ***moon growing larger or smaller in the sky,*** during a month, and thus having more or less ‘pull’ or effect, or intensity, towards the planet.

The moon is ‘**waxing’ when it is growing in size,** and moving towards being a full moon, and ‘**waning’ when it is declining in size** and moving towards being a crescent or new moon.

‘**Wax**’ in this sense means ‘to tend towards’ or ‘to move towards intensity’. It is likening someone to the growing moon. (Whereas ‘wane’ would be the opposite).

Bizarrely, dictionaries online talk about ‘waxing and waning’ meaning ‘to move towards or away’ from something - but seem to have forgotten that this refers to the moon!

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/wax-and-wane

Here’s a link that explains the moon ‘waxing and waning’:

https://www.wikihow.com/Tell-Whether-the-Moon-Is-Waxing-or-Waning